# Type { jobPostings: ItemType<MenuItemType>[]; } is not assignable to type MenuProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm trying to use the Dropdown component from antd. I followed the documentation https://ant.design/components/dropdown but I'm receiving the following error: **TS2322: Type  { jobPostings: ItemType[]; }  is not assignable to type  MenuProps 
Object literal may only specify known properties, and  jobPostings  does not exist in type  MenuProps**.

This is my code. These are the options for the dropdown menu:

```
const jobPostings: MenuProps['items'] = [
    {
      key: '1',
      label: (
          <a href="#">
            DevOps
          </a>
      ),
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      label: (
          <a href="#">
            UX designer
          </a>
      ),
    },
    {
      key: '3',
      label: (
          <a href="#">
            Full-stack developer
          </a>
      ),
    },
  ];
```

The dropdown component:

```
<Dropdown menu={{ jobPostings }} placement="bottom">
  <Button>bottom</Button>
</Dropdown>
```

Comment: `menu={{ items: jobPostings }}`